# How to prevent StatsPlots.jl reordering categorical data

Tags: julia, plots.jl

If I plot a boxplot using StatsPlots.jl with categorical data on the x axis, StatsPlots.jl orders the axis alphabetically. How can I stop this from happening?

```
using DataFrames
using StatsPlots

plotly()

df = DataFrame(grade=[rand(4:0.5:6, 40)...,
                      rand(5:0.5:8, 20)...,
                      rand(8:0.5:10, 10)...], 
               experience=[fill("beginner", 40)..., 
                           fill("advanced", 20)...,
                           fill("expert", 10)...])

boxplot(df.experience, df.grade, label=nothing)
```

[image]

Comment: Not a solution, but CategoricalArrays are precisely supposed to address this use case if only we found a way to fix https://github.com/JuliaData/CategoricalArrays.jl/issues/256.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Very informative.

Answer (score 1):

One can use a left-right space-padding trick:

```
xorder = ["beginner" "expert" "advanced"]
Nx = length(xorder)
str = fill("",length(df.experience))
for (i,xi) in enumerate(xorder)
    j = findall(x->x==xi, df.experience)
    si = " "^(Nx-i)
    @. str[j] = si * string(df.experience[j]) * si
end

# solution by left-right space-padding strings
@df df boxplot(str, :grade, fillalpha=0.75, linewidth=1, label=nothing)
```

*PS: Input uses random, so graphic changes every time.*

[image]

Comment: haha, yeah that works. But it's a little bit hacky. I would like a cleaner solution. People reading my code should easily understand what's going on, and the spaces will bite back at some point.

Comment: The leading and trailing spaces do not seem to print out, not deleting any other characters from neighbor labels. At least in my limited testing they did seem to act transparently / be ignored in the plot display process.